# Concatenate select rows into one row without space in R (using forloop)

Tags: r, for-loop, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate multiple rows into one.

Each row, it is either start with ">Gene Identifier" or Sequence information

> *>Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714
>   GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTC
>   AGGCGGAGA*
>
> *>Laptm4a|ENSMUSG00000020585|ENSMUST00000020909
>   GCAGTGACAAAGACAACGTGGCGAAAGACAGCGCCAAAAATCTCCGTGCCCGCTGTCTGC
>   CACCAACTCCGTCTTGTTTCACCCTTCTCCTCCTTGCGGAGCTCGTCTGGGAGACGGTGA
>   ATTACCGAGTTACCCTCAATTCCTACAGCCCCCGACAGCGAGCCCAGCCACGCGCACCGC
>   GGTCAAACAGCGCCGGAGAGAGTTGAACTTTTGATTGGGCGTGATCTGTTTCAATCTCCA
>   CATCTTCTCCAATCAGAAGCCAGGTAGCCCGGCCTTCCGCTCTTCGTTGGTCTGT*

Here I just put two genes, but there are hundreds of genes following this. 
Basically I will just leave the gene identifier as this, but I want to concatenate sequences only when it is separated into multiple rows.

Therefore, the final results should look like this:
The sequences were concatenated and combined into one row, without any space inbetween.

> *>Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714
>   GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTCAGGCGGAGA*
>
> *>Laptm4a|ENSMUSG00000020585|ENSMUST00000020909
>   GCAGTGACAAAGACAACGTGGCGAAAGACAGCGCCAAAAATCTCCGTGCCCGCTGTCTGCCACCAACTCCGTCTTGTTTCACCCTTCTCCTCCTTGCGGAGCTCGTCTGGGAGACGGTGAATTACCGAGTTACCCTCAATTCCTACAGCCCCCGACAGCGAGCCCAGCCACGCGCACCGCGGTCAAACAGCGCCGGAGAGAGTTGAACTTTTGATTGGGCGTGATCTGTTTCAATCTCCACATCTTCTCCAATCAGAAGCCAGGTAGCCCGGCCTTCCGCTCTTCGTTGGTCTGT*

By using "paste" function in R, I was able to achieve this manually.
i.e. paste(dat[2,1], dat[3,1], sep="")

However, I have a list of hundreads of gene, so I need a way to concatenate rows automatically.

I was thinking forloop, basically, if the row starts from ">", skip it, but if it is not start from ">", concatenate.

But I'm not expert in bioinformatics/R, it is hard for me to actually generate a script to achieve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something happened when I pasted this into the answer box to concatenate the data lines but they were separate in my R session so this should work:

```
Lines <- 
readLines(textConnection(">*>Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714
GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTCAGGCGGAGA*

>*>Laptm4a|ENSMUSG00000020585|ENSMUST00000020909
GCAGTGACAAAGACAACGTGGCGAAAGACAGCGCCAAAAATCTCCGTGCCCGCTGTCTGCCACCAACTCCGTCTTGTTTCACCCTTCTCCTCCTTGCGGAGCTCGTCTGGGAGACGGTGAATTACCGAGTTACCCTCAATTCCTACAGCCCCCGACAGCGAGCCCAGCCACGCGCACCGCGGTCAAACAGCGCCGGAGAGAGTTGAACTTTTGATTGGGCGTGATCTGTTTCAATCTCCACATCTTCTCCAATCAGAAGCCAGGTAGCCCGGCCTTCCGCTCTTCGTTGGTCTGT*
"))

 geneIdx <- grepl("\\|", Lines)
  grp <- cumsum(geneIdx)
 grp
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2

 tapply(Lines, grp, FUN=function(x) c(x[1], paste(x[-1], collapse="") ) )
#----------------------
$`1`
[1] ">*>Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714"                      
[2] "GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTCAGGCGGAGA*"

$`2`
[1] ">*>Laptm4a|ENSMUSG00000020585|ENSMUST00000020909"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[2] "GCAGTGACAAAGACAACGTGGCGAAAGACAGCGCCAAAAATCTCCGTGCCCGCTGTCTGCCACCAACTCCGTCTTGTTTCACCCTTCTCCTCCTTGCGGAGCTCGTCTGGGAGACGGTGAATTACCGAGTTACCCTCAATTCCTACAGCCCCCGACAGCGAGCCCAGCCACGCGCACCGCGGTCAAACAGCGCCGGAGAGAGTTGAACTTTTGATTGGGCGTGATCTGTTTCAATCTCCACATCTTCTCCAATCAGAAGCCAGGTAGCCCGGCCTTCCGCTCTTCGTTGGTCTGT*"
```

Comment: I have only one issue though. when the rows were separated, it generates nice concatenated results as you showed. first column as gene name, and 2nd column as sequence information -->  [1] ">Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714"                        
[2] "GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTCAGGCGGAGAC"

Comment: However, when the original sequences were short enough that did not have separate row at the first place, it generate one row showing both gene name and sequences in the same row. Example as follow -->  [1] ">Stk35|ENSMUSG00000037885|ENSMUST00000165413" "GGCTCTCCGCTGGCCTCCTGGGGG"

Comment: This one has 'one row indicated as [1], and both gene name and sequences are in the same row. is there any ways to avoid this? I will look up and study tapply and others to figure out my self, but if you can advice me that will be awesome!!

Comment: I wondered about reading it in and using the pipes ("|") as separators. You need to edit your question to put in edge cases for testing.

Comment: Sorry BondedDust, I looked up my R session again, and your method was actually perfectly working!!. I was confused because some of the sequences were short. It turns out it is simply because my screen was too wide. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would regular expressions do the trick? The regular expression below deletes newlines (`\\n`) not followed by `>` (`(?!>)` being a *negative lookahead*).

```
text <-">Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714
GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTC
AGGCGGAGA

>Laptm4a|ENSMUSG00000020585|ENSMUST00000020909
GCAGTGACAAAGACAACGTGGCGAAAGACAGCGCCAAAAATCTCCGTGCCCGCTGTCTGC
CACCAACTCCGTCTTGTTTCACCCTTCTCCTCCTTGCGGAGCTCGTCTGGGAGACGGTGA
ATTACCGAGTTACCCTCAATTCCTACAGCCCCCGACAGCGAGCCCAGCCACGCGCACCGC
GGTCAAACAGCGCCGGAGAGAGTTGAACTTTTGATTGGGCGTGATCTGTTTCAATCTCCA
CATCTTCTCCAATCAGAAGCCAGGTAGCCCGGCCTTCCGCTCTTCGTTGGTCTGT"

cat(text)

cat(gsub("\\n(?!>)", "", text, perl=TRUE))
```

#### Result

```
>Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714GCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTCAGGCGGAGA
>Laptm4a|ENSMUSG00000020585|ENSMUST00000020909GCAGTGACAAAGACAACGTGGCGAAAGACAGCGCCAAAAATCTCCGTGCCCGCTGTCTGCCACCAACTCCGTCTTGTTTCACCCTTCTCCTCCTTGCGGAGCTCGTCTGGGAGACGGTGAATTACCGAGTTACCCTCAATTCCTACAGCCCCCGACAGCGAGCCCAGCCACGCGCACCGCGGTCAAACAGCGCCGGAGAGAGTTGAACTTTTGATTGGGCGTGATCTGTTTCAATCTCCACATCTTCTCCAATCAGAAGCCAGGTAGCCCGGCCTTCCGCTCTTCGTTGGTCTGT
```

Comment: Thank you Ian, I tried it, but it seems like your method works only when each rows are separated by 'n'. My original datasets are separated by individual row. if I can combine each row I think this method also should work. I will try more.

Comment: @gdy : The `\\n` actually refers to the newline character (`\n`), with the extra backslash being used to "escape" this character. It may be that you don't have newline characters between your lines (e.g., I think this happens on Windows). I think you can use `str()` to identify what is separating your lines:

`> str(text)
chr ">Zfyve21|ENSMUSG00000021286|ENSMUST00000021714\nGCGGGCGGGGCGGGGTGGCGCCTTGTGTGGGCTCAGCGCGGGCGGTGGCGTGAGGGGCTC\nAGGCGGAGA\n\n>Lap"| __truncated__`

Comment: Oh I see, I think I got your strategy. But I'm not sure how to check the newline character. When I just try >cat(mydata), all rows are now concatenated and there is a space inbetween, not \n as you indicated. That might be the issue. Thank you!!!

Comment: @gdy I was using `str()` not `cat()` to "see" the character.